# Xamarin Forms: How to use Embedded Videos from local forlder?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials, xamarin-community-toolkit

I've tried looking for a solution but I cannot find one everyone seems to be using online sources and no one actually shows how to use videos from the local folder.

I want to have a folder under `Assets` for Android and `Resources` for iOS called `Videos` and store all necessary videos there. I don't have a clue how to access them tho to add to my source for `MideaElement` from Xamarin Community Toolkit.

I found a solution for embedded images but it doesn't work the same for videos. [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVpbklb6vDc&ab_channel=XamarinDevelopers)

IDK if they need to be embedded or not, or can I just access them with a relative path of sort?

I've read the documentation for `MediaElement` and their local way of access videos but I do not understand it with thing like `ms-appx:///` & `ms-appdata:///` where do they point to? where do I put my own resources? how do I use that to access my own resource? So many questions but 0 answers.

This is the documentation on [MediaElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/mediaelement).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/mediaelement#play-media-embedded-in-the-app-package) you link to explain **exactly** where to place the files on each platform

- On iOS, media files must be stored in the Resources folder, or a subfolder of the Resources folder. The media file must have a Build Action of BundleResource.
- On Android, media files must be stored in a subfolder of Resources named raw. The raw folder cannot contain subfolders. The media file must have a Build Action of AndroidResource.

Comment: Yeah I feel really stupid now missing the step by step explanation. :FACEPALM: